# Update JTable when Data changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

The question might been answered already and I read many similar ones but doesn't work for me. So I have my `JTable` with Custom Table model that extends `DefaultTableModel`. My data is `Object[][] data` and Column Names `String[] columnNames`. So when my data changes how do I update the table? I have been using `tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames)` and it is working but it resets my custom cell renderer to default. Thanks.

Comment: In what respect does your data change? Is it changed via the table or via some other external means? The table API is capable of managing itself, so changing the values via the table shouldn't require any additional input from you. Changes made externally are a little more complicated, depending on the amount of change.  You could call TableModel#setValueAt for simple changes or replace the JTable's model altogether for more complex chmages

Comment: My data changes like this: data[0][0] was for example 5 and now it is 10. So how I make that change to the table also? Or you think i should not display data via tableModel.setDataVector(..) and use table.setValue(..) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't change the Arrays! The DefaultTableModel will copy the data from the Arrays to the internal storage used by the DefaultTableModel.

Instead, you need to change the TableModel directly by using the `setValueAt(...)` method of the JTable or the TableModel. The TableModel will then notify the table that changes have been made.

> I have been using `tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames)` and it is working but it resets my custom cell renderer to default

If you need to recreate the entire TableModel for some reason then you can use:

```
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
```

AFTER you create the table using a TableModel the first time. Now the next time you use the `setDataVector(...)` method the `TableColumnModel` of the table will NOT be recreated which means you won't lose the custom renderers.

Comment: Hm. Sounds good. But what should be required "reason" for recreating entire table model? In my case I have a table with some Articles and their number stats. So when the user types the new state in the following column, the column after shows the difference and the money income. Is that a reason to recreate entire table model or I should stick with the table.setValue(..) ?

Comment: @ЂорђеЂашић, You are changing the value of one cell so you use the setValueAt(...) method. `But what should be required "reason" for recreating entire table model?` - when you change all the data. Maybe you query a database.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for explaining. I understand now. Best wishes! I will accept answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer - mega useful!